# Get the word between the <a></a> tag

Tags: php, html

if i have an html line like:

```
<a href="your.link-and-stuf.php" title="here your page title and stuf">this word</a>
```

I want "this word" get out of it with php.
I tried with str_replace() but i didn't get far. Because the link changes.

So how can i do this?

Comment: preg_match or http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simply solution is to use the built in function `strip_tags` a complex solution would be using regular expressions

**Strip Tags Implementation**

```
$str = '<a href="your.link-and-stuf.php" title="here your page title and stuf">this word</a>';
$strip = strip_tags($str);

echo $strip; // this word
```

**Regular Expression Matching**

```
$str = '<a href="your.link-and-stuf.php" title="here your page title and stuf">this word</a>';
$strip = preg_replace("/<\\/?a(\\s+.*?>|>)/", "", $str); // removes only a tags

echo $strip; // this word
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use a library like [simplehtmldom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/).

The code might look something like:

```
$html = str_get_html('<a href="your.link-and-stuf.php" title="here your page title and stuf">this word</a>');
$text = $html->find('a', 0)->innerText;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.construct.php)

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<a href="your.link-and-stuf.php" title="here your page title and stuf">this word</a>');
echo $doc->getElementsByTagName('a')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```